# Is there any way to hide the long divider lines in PostgreSQL's expanded output?

Tags: postgresql

In `psql`, with `\x` toggled to expanded output mode, I get these very long wrapped dashed lines for record separators when there is a field with a long string value in one of the selected records. They look like

-[ RECORD 2 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (is much longer)

Is there any way to suppress or shorten these lines? I'm on PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try \t:

```
test=# select * from test limit 1;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------
id      | 1
name    | foo

test=# \t
Showing only tuples.
test=# select * from test limit 1;
id      | 1
name    | foo
```

[Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html).

---

Also try:

```
test=# \pset border 0
Border style is 0.
backend=# select * from test limit 2;
id      1
name    foo

id      2
name    bar
```

Comment: I still get long wrapped divider lines, though without the [ RECORD n ].

Comment: Try what I suggested in my follow-up edit. It also gets rid of the border.

Comment: OK I tried the second, but now the long wrapped lines have been replaced by empty space. So the records are separated by many blank lines.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? I doubt you'll be able to get anything better. \x comes to mind if your number of columns are large, but you already seem to know that one.

Comment: I just seems that MySQL's `\G` option formats records with fields with very long text values better than `\x` on psql.

Comment: Well, having the records separated by 20 blank lines so that I can only see maybe one or two records per screen is not really ideal. But I guess I can live with it until Postgres improves its expanded output

Comment: Here's a last one to try: `\pset format wrapped` (defaults to `\pset format aligned`).

Comment: You might want to report this in pg-bugs, by the way. It'll never be on anyone's radar if it's not reported.

Comment: To see what my issue is, try adding a text column to your table, and create 2 records with very long strings of text in that field, and then try to see what select * from table looks like with \x toggled on.

Comment: OK I tried \pset format wrapped. No change. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I've sent a report to PG Bugs, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, using these two psql command line flags solved the issue for me:

- `\x` (good for records with lots of columns)
- `\pset format wrapped` (wraps the postgres output to your terminal width)

I got the response from this [dba stackexchange article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/how-to-wrap-long-lines-when-selecting-sql-text-columns)

Comment: Good answer. I am experiencing `\t` (however it is toggled) not suppressing that very long, very annoying divider line. Explicitly setting `\x on` and `\pset format wrapped` in my psql terminal worked well, per this screenshot (https://persagen.com/files/misc/postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png). You can later override that setting with `\x auto` and `\pset format aligned`.

Comment: Thank you -- `\pset format wrapped` was the best solution I've seen.

Comment: `\pset format wrapped` was exactly what I was looking for.  Also useful to know: instead of `;`, use `\gx (format=wrapped)` if you just want this behavior for a single query, rather than having to `\pset` before and after the query.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and just learned about https://www.pgcli.com/, and it fixes this issue by default, and has a host of other features.